# how to insert parsed xml data in to sql lite database in android

Tags: android, xml, sqlite

I have parsed xml data but I don't know how to insert it into a SQL Lite database and I don't know where I have to place the xml database file in Eclipse IDE folders.

Kindly provide some example program with deployment descriptor.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

So far, I've only worked with creating (or updating) databases at runtime.  If you want to include a database in your actual apk, then you'll need to copy the file into the databases directory.  If that sounds like what you're trying to do, take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/).

If you just need to know how to work with a database in general, check out [SQLite](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db) in the android documentation.  Basically you want to make your own Helper class that extends SQLiteHelper, then create an actual Database class that makes use of the helper.